# Updating a source file in referenced project assembly in VS2012 -a bug?

Tags: asp.net, reference, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly

In a web site I have a reference to a class library assembly. When I add something to the source code and build the solution the update does not reflect to the bin folder of the web site. I first thought dll refresh did not work so that the dll in my bin folder was not updated to the latest version. But then I found two things that seem weird:

1. I have a public struct inside which are number of public const string fields. If I change the name of any of those fields and build solution, the change does not get reflected on the web site side. However if I select that field name, right click on it and choose "Rename oldname to newname" and then build, it works.
2. When I add another public const string field and build the solution, the update does not get reflected.

Is this a know bug with VS2012 or is this an intended feature? I can understand the first case. But the second case absolutely seems to be a bug and there's nothing like intended feature. I wanted to check with SO before reporting this to VS team as a bug.

I did not use to have this problem with Visual Studio 2010 ultimate. The current one I'm using is Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Comment: Are both projects in the same solution? Is it a web site or a web application project.

Comment: Yes, they're in the same solution. Actually it's a website project. I've updated the question

Comment: Web site "projects" are weird. Use web application projects instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely seems to be a bug. I've already reported this to Visual Studio team. But for the ones who suffer from this bug I have a solution until the bug is fixed.

1. Remove the reference from the bin folder. (x.dll, x.pdb, x.dll.refresh and x.XML files where x is the name of the referenced project.)
2. Select your web site or project, right click and click Add reference
3. This is the part that made a difference. On the left pane select Solution||Projects. Click Browse at the lower right side of the window if the project you want to reference is not in the list on the middle pane and navigate to that project, it'll come to the list. Check the box and click OK. I used to select Browse (not Solution||Projects) and reference directly the dll file. What you will notice with the first (working) option is x.dll.refresh file is missing. I know it sounds weird but I don't know how and why the referenced dll is updated when this file is missing.